# when we say "ich gehe ins Kino" ?

Tags: grammar

according to the german grammar we should say " ich gehe in dem kino " because "das Kino" is in the dative position >>> but why here ins not in dem

Comment: "Ich gehe in dem Kino" is correct - but only if you are walking around inside the cinema. If you are going *in**to*** the cinema, you need the accusative.

Comment: Who says that "Kino" is in a Dative position? What is a Dative position anyway? What's your source for the German grammar?